# Echo adding a random value

Tags: batch-file, random, echo

I have a batch file that create another batch file.

I need to add inside the echo a random function to have numbers from 1 to 6.

My batch code (works perfectly)

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::: Batch Code :::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

@echo off
    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("D:\Program files\Openvpn\openvpn_configuration_list_for_clicks.csv") do (
       echo :::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
       echo/
       echo MOVE /Y "D:\Program files\Openvpn\config_to_check\%%~NXa" "D:\Program files\Openvpn\config\"
       echo START "" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect %%~NXa
       echo PING -n 30 localhost ^>NUL 2^>^&1
       echo PING -n 5 www.wikipedia.org^|FIND /I "TTL"^>NUL
       echo IF NOT "%%ERRORLEVEL%%"=="1" ^(
       echo rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
       echo start "" "D:\Program files\Firefox Esr\FirefoxPortable.exe"
       echo TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK ^>NUL
       echo goto search_%%a
       echo ^)
       echo :search_%%a
       echo tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2^>NUL ^| find /I /N "firefox.exe"^>NUL
       echo if "%%ERRORLEVEL%%"=="0" ^(
       echo TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK ^>NUL
       echo goto search_%%a
       echo ^)
       echo if "%%ERRORLEVEL%%"=="1" ^(goto continue_%%a^)
       echo :continue_%%a
       echo taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe
       echo taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn-gui.exe
       echo MOVE /Y "D:\Program files\Openvpn\config\%%~NXa" "D:\Program files\Openvpn\config_to_check\"
       echo/
       echo :::: End Of The Command Block ::::
       echo/
       echo/
       echo/
    )) > "D:\Program files\Openvpn\final.bat"
       (echo exit) >> "D:\Program files\Openvpn\final.bat"
```

openvpn_configuration_list_for_clicks.csv (list of vpn)

```
vpn1.ovpn
vpn2.ovpn
vpn4.ovpn
vpn8.ovpn
```

output final.bat without random function (works perfectly)

```
:::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
MOVE /Y "D:\Program Files\Openvpn\config_to_check\vpn1.ovpn" "D:\Program Files\Openvpn\config\"
START "" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect vpn1.ovpn
PING -n 30 localhost >NUL 2>&1
PING -n 5 www.wikipedia.org|FIND /I "TTL">NUL
IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox Esr\FirefoxPortable.exe"
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK >NUL
goto search_vpn1.ovpn
)
:search_vpn1.ovpn
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "firefox.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK >NUL
goto search_vpn1.ovpn
)
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (goto continue_vpn1.ovpn)
:continue_vpn1.ovpn
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn-gui.exe
MOVE /Y "D:\Program Files\Openvpn\config\vpn1.ovpn" "D:\Program Files\Openvpn\config_to_check\"

:::: End Of The Command Block ::::
```

I need a solution to have a random number from 1 to 6 in path inside echo

```
"D:\Program Files\Firefox Esr 2\FirefoxPortable.exe"
```

or

```
"D:\Program Files\Firefox Esr 5\FirefoxPortable.exe"
```

or

```
"D:\Program Files\Firefox Esr 6\FirefoxPortable.exe"
```

The code without a random function works very well and generates output correctly, I need to insert a random function inside the code that does not send the output generation into error.

The random function need to calculate for every loop to have a new random number for every loop

Comment: "*I have a batch file that create another batch file.*" Why?!

Comment: Because it extract some value from a text and combine it, after create an output in another file with the list of commands

Comment: I can advise you that there is no need to escape an opening parenthesis. Your issue however is that you are setting and using a variable within a code block, you will therefore need to use a pseudo call, delayed expansion or restructure the code. I would advise the latter.

Comment: Been writing batch files for well longer than I can remember. Can't say that I have ever needed to have a batch file create a batch file to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me step through my comment with some examples.

Your initial code was escaping opening parentheses unnecessarily and should have looked more like this:

```bat
    Echo :::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
    Echo/
    Echo Ping -n 30 localhost ^>Nul 2^>^&1
    Echo Ping -n 5 www.facebook.com^|Find /I "TTL"^>Nul
    Echo If Not "%%ErrorLevel%%"=="1" (
    Echo    Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
    Echo    Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^^^) + 1
    Echo    Start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox Portable %%num%%\FirefoxPortable.exe"
    Echo    Timeout 60 /NoBreak ^>Nul
    Echo ^)
    Echo/
    Echo :search
```

However, you are setting a variable and trying to use it within the same `If` block, this can be fixed in a number of ways:

1. Use a pseudo `Call` statement:

   ```bat
       Echo :::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
       Echo/
       Echo Ping -n 30 localhost ^>Nul 2^>^&1
       Echo Ping -n 5 www.facebook.com^|Find /I "TTL"^>Nul
       Echo If Not "%%ErrorLevel%%"=="1" (
       Echo    Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
       Echo    Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^^^) + 1
       Echo    Call Start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox Portable %%%%num%%%%\FirefoxPortable.exe"
       Echo    Timeout 60 /NoBreak ^>Nul
       Echo ^)
       Echo/
       Echo :search
   ```
2. Enable delayed expansion: *(this example assumes that delayed expansion isn't already enabled in the script doing the `Echo`ing)*

   ```bat
       Echo :::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
       Echo/
       Echo Ping -n 30 localhost ^>Nul 2^>^&1
       Echo Ping -n 5 www.facebook.com^|Find /I "TTL"^>Nul
       Echo If Not "%%ErrorLevel%%"=="1" (
       Echo    Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
       Echo    Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^^^) + 1
       Echo    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       Echo    Start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox Portable !num!\FirefoxPortable.exe"
       Echo    EndLocal
       Echo    Timeout 60 /NoBreak ^>Nul
       Echo ^)
       Echo/
       Echo :search
   ```
3. Enable delayed expansion: *(this example assumes that delayed expansion is already enabled in the script doing the `Echo`ing)*

   ```bat
       Echo :::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
       Echo/
       Echo Ping -n 30 localhost ^>Nul 2^>^&1
       Echo Ping -n 5 www.facebook.com^|Find /I "TTL"^>Nul
       Echo If Not "%%ErrorLevel%%"=="1" (
       Echo    Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
       Echo    Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^^^) + 1
       Echo    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       Echo    Start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox Portable ^!num^!\FirefoxPortable.exe"
       Echo    EndLocal
       Echo    Timeout 60 /NoBreak ^>Nul
       Echo ^)
       Echo/
       Echo :search
   ```
4. Restructure the code in order not to have an unnecessary `If` block *(preferred)*:

   ```bat
       Echo :::: Start Of The Command Block ::::
       Echo/
       Echo Ping -n 30 localhost ^>Nul 2^>^&1
       Echo Ping -n 5 www.facebook.com^|Find /I "TTL"^>Nul
       Echo If "%%ErrorLevel%%"=="1" GoTo search
       Echo Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
       Echo Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^) + 1
       Echo Start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox Portable %%num%%\FirefoxPortable.exe"
       Echo Timeout 60 /NoBreak ^>Nul
       Echo/
       Echo :search
   ```

---

All of the above examples assume that the code shown is inside a parenthesised block, similar to `(code above)>"another.bat"` or `>"another.cmd" (code above)`

---

**[Edit /]**

Here's some code to incorporate the additional stuff you've now posted. I have utilised methd `4.` from above to remove the unnecessary `If` blocks. It should also incorporate the randomisation function you require, which is the same as previously posted and compatible with your batch file.

```bat
@Echo Off
(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In (
    "D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\openvpn_configuration_list_for_clicks.csv") Do (
    Echo @Move /Y "D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config_to_check\%%~nxA" "D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config"
    Echo @Start "" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\OpenVPN-GUI.exe" --connect %%~nxA
    Echo @Timeout 30 /NoBreak^>Nul 2^>^&1
    Echo @Ping -n 5 www.wikipedia.org^|Find /I "TTL"^>Nul^|^|GoTo search_%%A
    Echo @Rundll32 User32.dll,MessageBeep 0x00000010L
    Echo @Set "num="
    Echo @Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^) + 1
    Echo @Start "" "D:\Program Files\Firefox ESR %%num%%\FirefoxPortable.exe"
    Echo @Timeout 60 /NoBreak^>Nul
    Echo/
    Echo :search_%%A
    Echo @TaskList^|Find /I "Firefox.exe"^>Nul^|^|GoTo continue_%%A
    Echo @Timeout 60 /NoBreak^>Nul
    Echo @GoTo search_%%A
    Echo/
    Echo :continue_%%A
    Echo @TaskKill /F /IM OpenVPN.exe 2^>Nul
    Echo @TaskKill /F /IM OpenVPN-GUI.exe 2^>Nul
    Echo @Move /Y "D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\%%~nxA" "D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config_to_check"
    Echo/))>"final.bat"
    Echo @Exit /B>>"D:\Program Files\OpenVPN\final.bat"
```

Comment: I tried first code but show an error "unexpected +" and the batch code stop to generate the output, I will try the other exaples and after if there are other problems I post the complete code of the batch file to study a solution to insert correctly tha random function without creating conflicts with the rest of code. This batch file performs many extraction functions and eventually generates a single batch file that once started loads various software. Thanks

Comment: It's here the + "Echo    Set /A num=(%%RANDOM%% %%%% 6^) + 1" i think the + Character create conflicts with the rest of code. It's hard to add in this batch file a random value, i tried from some days without success. i need only to add a random number from 1 to 6 at the folder firefox inside in the code

Comment: @camomillo, thank you for the feedback, I have looked at the examples and made a minor but important change to all examples except `4.`. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I added the complete code to make it easier to understand, I'm interested only in being able to insert a random number function in the batch without errors, otherwise the code works well without problems. If there is a code to generate a random number from 1 to 6, it is more compatible with my batch file. I thank you all

Comment: @camomillo, I have added an **[Edit /]** to my answer, to hopefully cater for your newly posted information. As you can see, I have removed all of the unnecessary `If` statements, in the hope of simplifying your task.

Comment: After various tests I choice the solution 2 that works like a charms with my code. The if statements have the function to check if firefox is opened and leave in wait the batch file, after firefox will be closed the if statement check task manager and do not find firefox process and continue the works with the next command. This batch file is very long and execute more command one after one. Your solution 2 is perfect for my case and the random numbers works. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @double-beep, as it is not relevant, to the question, only to the comment, it is deliberately separated from my answer, so thank you for your comment, despite it being absolutely irrelevant to the situation or the answers in the linked posts.